# SQLAlchemy 'after_insert' event on parent model in joined inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

It has only been a while since I've started tinkering with SQLAlchemy. I am building an application which has different type of users, each with different attributes. So I built a base User model and created all other user models using joined inheritance.

**User** model

```
class User(UserMixin, BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, unique=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False, index=True)
    confirmed = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    role = Column(Enum(Role))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on": role,
    }
```

I created **Role** as an Enum model

```
class Role(enum.Enum):
    
    admin = 1
    client = 2
    brand = 3
    merchant = 4
    customer = 5
    client_user = 6
    brand_user = 7
    merchant_user = 8
    anonymous = 9
```

Other user models are:

**Client**

```
class Client(User):

    __tablename__ = "clients"

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "client",
        'inherit_condition': (id == User.id)
    }
    client_data = (...)
    .....
```

**Brand**

```
class Brand(User):

    __tablename__ = "brands"


    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "brand",
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }
    brand_data = (...)
    .....
```

So and so forth...

It works as per the plan up until here. I've created an 'after_insert' event hook on the base User model

```
@event.listens_for(User, "after_insert")
def dispatch_confirmation_mail(mapper, connection, target):
    if not target.confirmed:
        _create_reauth_mail(target.email)
```

Now my the problems which I'm facing are :

1. When I'm creating a base User object the function hooked to
   "after_insert" is triggered, but when I'm creating a child User
   object it is not.
2. When querying `User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()`, it throws below error
   `AssertionError: No such polymorphic_identity <Role.client: 2> is defined`

Can anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your first problem is to add `propagate=True` to your `listens_for` decorator, so it becomes:

```py
@event.listens_for(User, "after_insert", propagate=True)
```

This makes sure that the event listener propagates to subclasses.